# kivy language file root vs. <root> - loading by convention vs. loading by a Builder

Tags: python, kivy

First of all, sorry for the long title, but I couldn't come up with a better way of phrasing my problem.

Hello, I'm a bit confused by a notation in the kivy language files: According to the first lines of [this](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html) document, the former syntax denotes a root item,

```
rootObj:
    Button:
        ....
```

whereas the latter one denotes some kind of rule:

```
<rootObj>:
    Button:
        ....
```

I thought that the former syntax describes what I call the root-object of that window as my python class, i.e. the python-class `rootObj` should be used as the root-object of my `example.kv`. Thus, I don't understand the purpose of the bracketed syntax. Suppose however, that I have the following files in a directory.

```
main.py
main.kv
```

main.py looks like this:

```
def rootObj(Widget):
    pass

def MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return rootObj()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
MainApp().run()
```

MainApp is run and by convention main.kv is loaded. Kivy calls `MainApp.build()` and that returns an instance of what I want to be the root-object. In order for this example to work, I must take the latter approach, which is specifying the name of the the root-object in those strange `<>` brackets. I wonder, why I have to specify the name of the root-Object when `MainApp.build()` does just that. Or am I totally mistaken here and kivy takes the rootObj() and appends the stuff in the `.kv-file`? Some enlightenment would come in handy.

If I now change the directory-structure to something like this...

```
 ui     
  \----main.kv     
 main.py
```

... and change `return rootObj()` to `return Builder.load_file("gui/main.kv")`, I suddenly have to use the bracketless syntax - but I don't know why.

Could someome explain the differences in the syntaxes and the internas of how kivy handles loading by convention and loading by the Builder-object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bracketed syntax creates *rules* for how a widget should behave. This rule will apply to any and every instance of that widget.

For instance, you could create a `MyButton` class in python and write the kv:

```
<MyButton>:
    background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)
```

That now means that *every* instance of MyButton, wherever and whenever it is created, will have this rule applied to it - in this case, just tinting its background red.

The other syntax, without the brackets, defines how to construct a single, specific instance of the class. The extra instructions won't apply to any other instances of that class, only the one returned by Builder when the file is loaded.

A kv file can only contain a single root widget declaration (without the brackets), but it can contain any number of normal rules.

For instance, you could have a kv file with something like:

```
RootObj:
    MyButton:
    MyButton:
    MyButton:

<MyButton>:
    background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)

<RootObj>:
    Label:
        text: 'label text'
```

Loading this with builder would return a single RootObj, with *4* child widgets - the Label defined by its normal rule, and the 3 `MyButton` instances (all tinted red according to their rule) created by the special root widget description.